# Draw heart symbol with drawString

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

I've tried `&#9825;`, `♥` and `\u2661` as text but I'm unable to draw the heart symbol.

```
g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
g2d.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 70));
g2d.drawString(text, 10, 10);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use `\u2665` instead of `\u2661`. Simply do:

```
g.setColor(Color.RED);
g.drawString("\u2665", 10, 10);
```

`\u2665` is the [unicode for heart shape](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2665/index.htm). For reference:

```
♥ \u2665
♦ \u2666
♣ \u2663
♠ \u2660
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem does not come with the fact that the heart isn't drawn. It *is* drawn but outside of the visible area.

You have specified a font size of 70 and you are drawing the heart at position `(10, 10)`. The [`Graphics2D.drawString(str, x, y)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#drawString-java.lang.String-float-float-) Javadoc specifies:

> The baseline of the first character is at position `(x, y)` in the User Space.

This means that the baseline for the heart will be at `y = 10` but since you have specified a font size of 70, you won't see it.

You should draw the String at a higher `y` value, like 100 for example:

```
g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
g2d.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 70));
g2d.drawString(text, 10, 100);
```

Side-note: `"\u2661"` (♡) is the Unicode value for a heart. If you want to draw a filled heart instead, use `"\u2665"` (♥).